# Restore .bak file to remote database

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a `test.bak` file in my local machine. I need to restore this file to remote machine's database. How do I do that?

When I try this, the remote database throws an error that it is not able to find `test.bak` on the local filesystem.

**Query**

```
RESTORE DATABASE TESTPROJECT 
FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.ICON3\MSSQL\Backup\test.bak'
```

**Error**

```
Cannot open backup device 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.ICON3\MSSQL\Backup\test.bak'. Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
```

How can I  achieve this? I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Are u referring to a local path or a server path to restore .bak file ?

Comment: Basically, the `.bak` file needs to be on a disk **on that machine** where your SQL Server software is running. You cannot restore to a `remote` server by having the `.bak` file on your local harddisk.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the context of this answer - `remote` refers to your machine, `local` is the database server.

---

**Restore from `local` filesystem**

Copy the backup file to the `local` filesystem, and restore directly from this copy.

*Prerequisites*

- Copy `test.bak` to `C:\test.bak` on the server

*Syntax*

```
RESTORE DATABASE TESTPROJECT FROM DISK = N'C:\test.bak';
```

---

**Restore from `remote` filesystem**

Alternatively you can restore from the `remote` backup file using [UNC syntax](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141941). I typically don't use this option, but it is useful if there won't be enough disk space on `local` filesystem for both the backup file and the restored database.

The success of this option depends on some variables - permissions on the `remote` filesystem assigned to the database service account, network health, and others.

*Prerequisites*

- `Remote` machine name is `remotemachine`
- Backup located on `remote` at `'C:\test.bak'`
- Database service account has access to the `remote` administrator share `C$`

*Syntax*

```
RESTORE DATABASE TESTPROJECT FROM DISK = N'\\remotemachine\c$\test.bak';
```

Comment: Hi Bryan, if appear "access is denied" and the file is shared with all persons, how can i make this?.